# Weighting output of cost function based on user input

Tags: math, weighted-average

Hi I am creating an android app that will generate a cycling route for users using a route finder.

I am trying to allow the user to either prefer distance or routes with cyclelanes present.

I have a slider from 0 to 10, where 0 means the user wants the shortest route, and 10 where the user wants roads with cyclelanes (if available).

The roads are represented as a graph and I have a function that calculate the shortest path from one point to another.

Given the output of this function: if there is a cyclelane present on the road I want to weight the result so that the higher the number the user chose, the lower the cost of the road and vice versa.

I am not really sure how weighted functions work.

Comment: Is a slider really the best way to collect such potentially serious user preferences as the presence of cycle lanes?

Answer (score 0):

if you calculate the route with dijkstra-like algorithm, in case of a cyclelane-edge, you should simply decrease the distance between two point by some value according to the slider-value